# Make R user-defined-function for data.table commands - How to refer a column properly

Tags: r, data.table, user-defined-functions, identity-column

I have the df1 data

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                        year=c(2014,2014,2015,2015),
                        month=c(1,2),
                        new.employee=c(4,6,2,6,23,2,5,34))

  id year month new.employee
1  A 2014     1            4
2  A 2014     2            6
3  A 2015     1            2
4  A 2015     2            6
5  B 2014     1           23
6  B 2014     2            2
7  B 2015     1            5
8  B 2015     2           34
```

and desired outcome with following functions:

```
library(data.table) # V1.9.6+
temp <- setDT(df1)[month == 2L, .(id, frank(-new.employee)), by = year]
df1[temp, new.employee.rank := i.V2, on = c("year", "id")]
df1
#    id year month new.employee new.employee.rank
# 1:  A 2014     1            4                 1
# 2:  A 2014     2            6                 1
# 3:  A 2015     1            2                 2
# 4:  A 2015     2            6                 2
# 5:  B 2014     1           23                 2
# 6:  B 2014     2            2                 2
# 7:  B 2015     1            5                 1
# 8:  B 2015     2           34                 1
```

Now, I want to datamining by creating a user-defined function to varying the input, which is new.employee in above example. I tried some ways but they did not work:

1. the first try:

   ```
   myRank <- function(data,var) {

    temp <- setDT(data)[month == 2L, .(id, frank(-var)), by = year]
    data[temp, new.employee.rank := i.V2, on = c("year", "id")]
    return(data)
   }        
   myRank(df1,new.employee)
   ```

   > Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'new.employee' not found
2. the second try:

   ```
   myRank(df1,df1$new.employee)
   ```

nothing appeared

3. The third try: I change the function a bit

   ```
   myRank <- function(data,var) {

   temp <- setDT(data)[month == 2L, .(id, rank(data$var)), by = year]
    data[temp, new.employee.rank := i.V2, on = c("year", "id")]
    return(data)
    }
   ```

   > myRank(df1,df1$new.employee)
   >      Warning messages:
   >      1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
   >      2: In `[.data.table`(setDT(data), month == 2L, .(id, rank(data$var)),  :
   >      Item 2 of j's result for group 1 is zero length. This will be filled with 2 NAs to match the longest column in this result. Later groups may have a similar problem but only the first is reported to save filling the warning buffer.
   >   3: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

I looked at similar problems but my R experience is not good enough to understand those.

Comment: There's really no value in posting R code as SO "snippets". It prevents one from seeing the whole problem. And with no explanation about what is desired I'm not sure how to interpret the request. (There's no R interpreter that will run R snippets.) Just use the code block operation.

Comment: Try to give the input as string i.e. "new.employee".

Comment: @docendo : it did not work by formating new.employee as string.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` uses a non standard evaluation by default (unless you start to mess around with `with = FALSE`), and thus, you will need to refer to your column by name or alternatively use `get`. Another problem with your code (as mentioned in comments) is that you are calling `new.employee` while it's not defined outside of the scope of `df1`. If you want prevent from R from evaluating it before you pass it to your data set, you could use the `deparse(substitute(var))` combination which will prevent evaluation and then convert `var` to a character string which can in turn be passed to `get` or the `eval(as.name())` combination (which do entirely different things but within the `data.table` scope will lead to the same result).
Finally, there is the printing issue after using `:=` within the function. Even if everything works, `return(data)` won't do anything, you will need to force printing either by using an additional `[]` or by explicitly calling `print`

Here's a possible solution

```
myRank <- function(data, var) {
  var <- deparse(substitute(var)) ## <~~~ Note this
  temp <- setDT(data)[month == 2L, .(id, frank(-get(var))), by = year] ## <~~ Note the get
  data[temp, new.employee.rank := i.V2, on = c("year", "id")][] ## <~~ Note the []
}       
myRank(df1, new.employee)
#    id year month new.employee new.employee.rank
# 1:  A 2014     1            4                 1
# 2:  A 2014     2            6                 1
# 3:  A 2015     1            2                 2
# 4:  A 2015     2            6                 2
# 5:  B 2014     1           23                 2
# 6:  B 2014     2            2                 2
# 7:  B 2015     1            5                 1
# 8:  B 2015     2           34                 1
```

Or

```
myRank <- function(data, var) {
  var <- as.name(deparse(substitute(var))) ## <~~~ Note additional as.name
  temp <- setDT(data)[month == 2L, .(id, frank(-eval(var))), by = year] ## <~ Note the eval
  data[temp, new.employee.rank := i.V2, on = c("year", "id")][]
} 
myRank(df1, new.employee)
#    id year month new.employee new.employee.rank
# 1:  A 2014     1            4                 1
# 2:  A 2014     2            6                 1
# 3:  A 2015     1            2                 2
# 4:  A 2015     2            6                 2
# 5:  B 2014     1           23                 2
# 6:  B 2014     2            2                 2
# 7:  B 2015     1            5                 1
# 8:  B 2015     2           34                 1
```

I would guess the second option will be faster as it avoids extracting the whole column out of `data`

---

As a side note, you could also make the creation of the new variables names interactive by replacing

```
new.employee.rank := i.V2
```

with something like

```
paste0("New.", var, ".rank") := i.V2
```

Comment: @ David: thank you David. Although I have not finished my data collecting, I have had some mini-test by creating some small-simple UDF as you suggested and it worked. Thank you so much and I will further update